# Manipulação de matrizes em python com módulo numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Como eu faço uma permuta de *linhas* de matrizes, usando numpy?

Preciso disso pra implementar o método de Gauss-Jordan de solução de sistemas lineares com pivotação parcial.

Comment: Talvez isso seja útil no futuro para quem veja a pergunta: [aqui são explicadas as três operações matriciais](http://schneiderfelipe.xyz/sistemas-lineares/#Solu%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-sistemas-lineares:-a-ideia-b%C3%A1sica) para o método de Gauß-Jordan com Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se por "permuta" você quer dizer transpor linhas x colunas, você faz assim:

```
import numpy as np

teste = np.array([i for i in range(1,41)]).reshape((10,4))
print('Normal:')
print(teste)

print('Transposta:')
print(teste.T)
```

Resultado:

```
Normal:
[[ 1  2  3  4]
 [ 5  6  7  8]
 [ 9 10 11 12]
 [13 14 15 16]
 [17 18 19 20]
 [21 22 23 24]
 [25 26 27 28]
 [29 30 31 32]
 [33 34 35 36]
 [37 38 39 40]]
Transposta:
[[ 1  5  9 13 17 21 25 29 33 37]
 [ 2  6 10 14 18 22 26 30 34 38]
 [ 3  7 11 15 19 23 27 31 35 39]
 [ 4  8 12 16 20 24 28 32 36 40]]
```

Se, por outro lado, você quer dizer "trocar" uma linha pela outra mesmo, então você faz assim:

```
import numpy as np

teste = np.array([i for i in range(1,41)]).reshape((10,4))
print('Normal:')
print(teste)

print('Permutada:')
salva = np.copy(teste[1])
teste[1] = teste[5]
teste[5] = salva
print(teste)
```

Resultado:

```
Normal:
[[ 1  2  3  4]
 [ 5  6  7  8]
 [ 9 10 11 12]
 [13 14 15 16]
 [17 18 19 20]
 [21 22 23 24]
 [25 26 27 28]
 [29 30 31 32]
 [33 34 35 36]
 [37 38 39 40]]
Permutada:
[[ 1  2  3  4]
 [21 22 23 24]
 [ 9 10 11 12]
 [13 14 15 16]
 [17 18 19 20]
 [ 5  6  7  8]
 [25 26 27 28]
 [29 30 31 32]
 [33 34 35 36]
 [37 38 39 40]]
```